# How Numeric literal with underscore works in java and why it was added as part of jdk 1.7

Tags: java, java-7

Can somebody please explain to me why this feature was added in JDK 7 and how it works?

While going through the new features of JDK 7, I found following code.

```
int i;
//Java 7 allows underscore in integer
i=3455_11_11;
```

Comment: see the [technotes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html)

Comment: You can read about it here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This is used to group the digits in your numeric (say for example for credit card etc)

From [Oracle Website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html):

> In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal. This feature enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric literals, which can improve the readability of your code.
>
> For instance, if your code contains numbers with many digits, you can
>   use an underscore character to separate digits in groups of three,
>   similar to how you would use a punctuation mark like a comma, or a
>   space, as a separator.

To conclude, it's just for a sake of readability.

Answer (score 54):

See [Underscores in Numeric Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html):

> In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can
>   appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal. This feature
>   enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric
>   literals, which can improve the readability of your code.

Try this:

```
int num = 111_222;
System.out.println(num); //Prints 111222
```

This feature was added due to the fact that long numbers can be hard to read sometimes, so instead of counting how many "zeros" a number has to figure out if it's a million or one hundred thousand, you can do:

`int myNum = 1_000_000;`

Now it's easy to see that there is two groups of 3 zeros, and clearly the number is million. Compare it with:

`int myNum = 1000000;`

Admit.. here you had to count each zero..

Answer (score 8):

JDK 7 `_` for numeric literals feature is only for the sake of readability. As per [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html):

> In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can
>   appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal. This feature
>   enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric
>   literals, which can improve the readability of your code.

Answer (score 5):

The underscore is completely ignored in Integer literals. It may be added to, for example, group digits in long numbers in groups of 3 (like you do in texts).